# Table with sequential name postfix in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse, postgresql-9.3

I am reading the legacy datawarehouse in postgresql and found a list of tables named like

command

```
\list
```

result:

```
abc_1
abc_2
abc_3
...
abc_10000
```

what do these sequential named tables in postgresql in the context of datawarehouse mean ? Why don't we just merge them into one table abc

Comment: They mean that someone created table names with numbers at the end. Nothing more

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 4 mins ago  thanks for the response. seems to be extremely bad design. is there special reason for that ?

Comment: Do all tables look the same? Is there a pattern in the data in this tables? Like each table has a specific range, or data from specific times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely likely that these will be *partitions* of a parent table `abc`. Check with `\d+ abc_1`. Does it mention any inheritance or parent table?

Even if they aren't part of an inheritance scheme it's likely to be partitioning, just handled at the application level.

Partitioning is a useful workaround for limitations in the database engine. In an ideal world it wouldn't be necessary, but in reality it can help some workloads and query patterns.